# Read line by line in Bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I want to do the following: Read a file line by line and use the line as a parameter.

```
FILE="cat test"
echo "$FILE" | \
while read CMD; do
echo $CMD
done
```

But when I do `echo $CMD`, it just prints `cat test`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

What you have is piping the text `"cat test"` into the loop.

You just want:

```
cat test | \
while read CMD; do
    echo $CMD
done
```

Answer (score 153):

The best way to do this is to redirect the file into the loop:

```
# Basic idea. Keep reading for improvements.
FILE=test

while read CMD; do
    echo "$CMD"
done < "$FILE"
```

A redirection with `< "$FILE"` has a few advantages over `cat "$FILE" | while ...`. It avoids a [useless use of cat](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), saving an unnecessary child process. It also avoids a common pitfall where the loop runs in a subshell. In Bash, commands in a `|` pipeline run in subshells, which means variable assignments are lost after the loop ends. Redirection with `<` doesn't have that problem, so you could use `$CMD` after the loop or modify other variables inside the loop. It also, again, avoids unnecessary child processes.

There are some additional improvements that could be made:

- Add `IFS=` so that `read` won't trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line.
- Add `-r` to `read` to prevent backslashes from being interpreted as escape sequences.
- Lower-case `CMD` and `FILE`. The Bash convention is that only environmental and internal shell variables are uppercase.
- Use `printf` in place of `echo` which is safer if `$cmd` is a string like `-n`, which `echo` would interpret as a flag.

```
file=test

while IFS= read -r cmd; do
    printf '%s\n' "$cmd"
done < "$file"
```

Comment: use << for HEREDOC and <<< for a variable containing lines like in my case.  As was pointed out using redirection instead of pipe is important for not invoking a subshell.

Answer (score 16):

`xargs` is the most flexible solution for splitting output into command arguments.

It is also very human readable and easy to use due to its simple parameterisation.

Format is `xargs -n $NUMLINES mycommand`.

For example, to `echo` each individual line in a file `/tmp/tmp.txt` you'd do:

```
cat /tmp/tmp.txt | xargs -n 1 echo
```

Or to `diff` each successive pair of files listed as lines in a file of the above name you'd do:

```
cat /tmp/tmp.txt | xargs -n 2 diff
```

The `-n 2` instructs `xargs` to consume and pass as separate arguments two lines of what you've piped into it at a time.

You can tailor `xargs` to split on delimiters besides carriage return/newline.

Use `man xargs` and google to find out more about the power of this versatile utility.

Comment: Should use `-a` of `xargs` instead of `cat`

Comment: or even better, redirect, which is POSIX compliant and more readable `< /tmp/tmp.txt xargs ...`

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean to do:

```
cat test | \
while read CMD; do
echo $CMD
done
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use each of the lines of the file as command-line params for your application you can use the xargs command.

```
xargs -a <params_file> <command>
```

A params file with:

```
a
b
c
d
```

and the file tr.py:

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

The execution of

```
xargs -a params ./tr.py
```

gives the result:

```
['./tr.py', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read CMD; do
    echo $CMD
done  << EOF
data line 1
data line 2
..
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct version of your script is as follows;

```
FILE="cat test"
$FILE | \
while read CMD; do
echo $CMD
done
```

However this kind of indirection --putting your command in a variable named FILE-- is unnecessary. Use one of the solutions already provided. I just wanted to point out your mistake.