# Bash script to read file line by line has stopped functioning overnight

Tags: bash, loops, file

This script worked perfectly for me last night but now has stopped with the error message
"Invalid syntax" pointing at the dollar sign in LINES=$(cat 'ytZiele.txt')

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

LINES=$(cat 'ytZiele.txt')

for LINE in $LINES

do    
    echo $LINE
done
```

Comment: On my system bash lives in /bin/bash, i.e. use /usr/bin/env bash.  What changed?  If the script didn't then there is something in $LINES that trigger shell magic.

Comment: Sorry, force of habit from python/perl. But using /bin/bash gives same error.

Comment: Use one of these to make the loop safe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642191/read-line-by-line-in-bash-script

Comment: Do you get the same error if remove everything after LINES?  I.e. minimize the problem.  If so, I would do a `od -a` of your script to make sure you don't have anything weird in it.  You could also try an empty ytZiele.txt file.

Comment: I get name 'LINES is not defined'

Comment: OK thanks but I found the problem, running the bash script in python instead of bash...told you old habits die hard. Thanks for all your help, genuine thanks, sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228774/discussion-between-allan-wind-and-hektor).

Answer (score 2):

The error messages do not make sense, and op figured out that he was running the bash script with python.